# What's the difference between these two crontab settings?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I'm looking at a crontab on a linux server and came accross the following line

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/file
```

To me this means run the cron every 1 minute right?

What makes it different from this?

```
* * * * * /path/to/file
```

I'm fairly new to Linux crontab so hopefully this isn't a dumb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'*/1' is a **step definition** and **means every minute; it is identical to the second format**.

If you would want to do something every 2 hours, you could do this:

```
* */2 * * * /path/to/file
```

See: (search for the word "Ranges")

```
man 5 crontab
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. The cron scheduler sees them both as 1 minute from the last run.